# Notification Hub Help on Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-notificationhub

I have Azure notification hub working on Xamarin Forms for iOS and Droid to receive general push notifications. I am trying to send a POSTID in my payload and then take that ID and direct to the data behind it.  My issue, I cannot seem to get the postid to read into the app. Every time I get an empty ID. The Push notification an Droid and are received, but the extra data, like postid are not.

{"aps":{"alert":"Test #03_01","postid":"8921"}}

Can someone point me to some documentation on this?  How to make it work with ID/data in the push notification behind the scene.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to promote your custom data fields. At the moment, they are in the "aps" section, which is reserved for data that will be consumed by APNS or iOS. Somewhere along the line your fields are being stripped.

Here's the APNS documentation for [building request payloads](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1).

For you it should look something like:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert":"Test #03_01"
    },
    "postid":"8921"
}
```